# Add leading zeros to the negative number in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

how to format below numbers in XSLT 1.0.The input is some times positive number and some times negative number.

input:

```
-4
-1
2
```

output:

```
00000-4
00000-1
0000002
```

Comment: Is that your current output, or your desired output?

Comment: that is my desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XSLT provides the [`format-number` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#format-number) which may help you here.

```
format-number(theNumber, '0000000')
```

would give you `0000002` for `2` and `-0000004` for `-4`.  But if you really do want to put the leading zeros before the minus sign in the negative case then the easiest approach is to simply treat the whole thing as a string manipulation rather than number formatting.  Define a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="zeros" select="'0000000'" />
```

and then say something like

```
concat(substring($zeros, string-length(theNumber)+1), theNumber)
```

The `substring` bit works out how many leading zeros to add, e.g. for `-4` it will take the substring of `$zeros` starting from the third character, i.e. five zeros.